# White border of 1px on image will not go away

Tags: html, css

So I have this SVG image Ièm trying to put in my website, but every time I get this white border... the code:

```
<div style="width: 100vw;height: 150px;background-image: url('wave1.svg');background-position: center;background-size: cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;margin: 0;"></div>
```

NOTE: I also tried having an img tag but it did the same thing... and my image file doesn't have white borders

Comment: Is this on a live site that you can post a link to? Or is this a local project? There isn't enough context in your question as is to help.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what could be causing this without seeing it in context. Can you add `border: none` to your styles and see if that fixes the issue? If the div containing the image does not have a border then it is likely the image.

Comment: Didn't do anything

Comment: If you can share the image or the code I think we will be able to offer more useful advice.

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you're talking about the edge around the image caused by the `margin` on `body`? Try:

```
body {
 margin: 0;
}
```

And see https://codepen.io/annaazzam/pen/yLeKZJW

Comment: my body has no margin... thats a weird phrase to say

Comment: just to make sure, I'm not saying you've added a margin yourself, there is always default margin on `body` and you need to explicitly set it to `0` :)